# removing package php-common fails on "phpsessionclean.timer"

Tags: debian, apt, php, dpkg

I'm running the latest Debian (Stretch/9.3.x) and preparing my system to install the latest PHP. I removed all pre-installed PHP packages except `php-common`.

While invoking `apt-get remove php-common` I get the error as follows

```
Removing php-common (1:49) ...
Failed to stop phpsessionclean.timer: Unit phpsessionclean.timer not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package php-common (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read phpsessionclean.timer
Failed to get unit file state for phpsessionclean.timer: No such file or directory
phpsessionclean.timer is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After some digging I tried `dpkg --purge php-common` and get this one

```
Removing php-common (1:49) ...
Failed to stop phpsessionclean.timer: Unit phpsessionclean.timer not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package php-common (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read phpsessionclean.timer
Failed to get unit file state for phpsessionclean.timer: No such file or directory
phpsessionclean.timer is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php-common
```

In fact it's quiet the same.

`dpkg --verify php-common`

```
??5??????   /lib/systemd/system/phpsessionclean.service
??5??????   /lib/systemd/system/phpsessionclean.timer
```

These files are really missing. But currently I don't know how to solve this. There's no help with `apt-get -f purge` nor `dpkg --remove --force-all`.

Comment: `Failed to stop phpsessionclean.service: Unit phpsessionclean.service not loaded.` and `Failed to disable unit: No such file or directory` ... tried with `phpsessionclean`, `phpsessionclean.service` and `phpsessionclean.timer` ... `--configure -a` does not helped anyway.

I think I'll try the latest live disc and do a c'n'p of the missing files. It may helps.

Comment: backup the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file then edit it by removing the `php-common` entry with its description , run `dpkg --configure -a` then update your system ,  it is not a proper way but it can be helpful.

Comment: lol ... I did, it worked, and after installing PHP 7.2 the package reappears while it's a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @GAD3R I **edited**

```
/var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and removed the whole `php-common` entry.

Thereafter I **run**

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

The updates / (dist-)upgrades are running well now.

---

**Edit (2018-01-09)**

My purpose on wiping all default php-packages was to install PHP 7.2. While the `php-common` package is a dependency it was reinstalled but now the `phpsessionclean.service` works properly as well.

---

**Edit (2018-01-09)**

While digging in my system for other broken packages I found this article

https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/02/21/debian-cleanup-tip-4-find-broken-packages-and-reinstall-them/

and reinstalled all found packages. But there was a package `colord` with a missing `colord.service`. So I did the same mentioned here and it worked like a charm.